# Create an Add-in Outlook MSI with Add-in Express from a classic .Net Add-in project

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, addin-express

I need to create an **.msi file** to install an **add-in for Outlook**. The project already exists but I want to generate the .msi with the **Add-in Express solution**.

The type of project that was used to make the old Add-in was an **Outlook VSTO Add-in project**.

**How can I generate the .msi file of my old project using Add-in Express?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the add-in project in the `Solution Explorer` window and then navigate through the context menu items:

[image: Create Setup Project Add-in Express]